# Python: If statement in double list comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I'm attempting to write the following list comprehension:

```
[writer for writer in writerList if problem in writer.solutions for problem in [1,2,3]]
```

The list comprehension is attempting to perform the following:

1. Look through each writer in writerList
2. Look through each item in the array [1,2,3]
3. If all the items in the array [1,2,3] are also present in writer.solutions, consider the writer. Else, discard the writer.

However, using the above list comprehension I am told that the local variable `problem` is referenced before assignment.

I suppose I am lacking a fundamental understanding of how to do this kind of double list comprehension where the if relies on the second comprehension. I would appreciate any light shined on the issue!

Comment: It looks like the first instance of `problem` should be `writer`

Comment: if should be at the end

Comment: `[writer for writer in writerList for problem in [1,2,3]  if problem in writer.solutions ]`

Comment: Is there a reason you're using a list comprehension? This task would be easier if you spread it out over a few lines. List comprehensions are great, but they can make complex loops difficult to understand.

Comment: Thank you very much everyone! So the suggested code fixes the syntax error. However, now there is a functional error. Instead of providing a list of writers where 1,2, and 3 are all in writer.solutions, it provides a writer where 1 is in writer.solutions, where 2 is in writer.solutions, and where 3 is in writer.solutions.

Comment: @BryanOakley - I realize that this would probably be fixed with a few lines of code, but I am trying to learn the limits of list comprehensions and how they could be used to succinctly retrieve a list of objects matching certain criteria. I'm using this for a filter function I am building.

Comment: I really wished that `map` was a method of list. You can consider `[w for w in winterList if all(map(lambda m: m in [1,2,3], w.solutions))]`, but it isn't a great solution. If `map` *was* a method of iterables (*a la* Pandas), you could have simply done `[w for w in winterList if all(w.solutions.map(lambda m: m in [1,2,3]))]`. If `map` and `all` were both methods to lists, you could have done `[w for w in winterList if w.solutions.map(lambda m: m in [1,2,3]).all()]`. But oh well, dreams will be dreams!

Comment: @ssm: If you need a `lambda` to use `map`, you're losing both speed and brevity; never, ever do it. You could just as easily express this as `[w for w in winterList if all(s in (1, 2, 3) for s in w.solutions)]` which is actually shorter and usually faster to boot. You could actually get (slightly) higher performance out of `map` if you used a C built-inand w.solutions` was large, but it looks ugly when you need to reference the special method: `[w for w in winterList if all(map((1, 2, 3).__contains__, w.solutions))]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This specific problem could possibly be optimized and simplified by using `sets` if the items in `writer.solutions` and `problems` are hashable (the integers you provide in your example are hashable, mutable items like dictionaries and lists aren't).

```
problems = set([1, 2, 3])
writers = [writer for writer in writerList if not problems.difference(writer.solutions)]
```

[`set.difference(other)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.difference) will return items in the set that aren't in the other.  So, if all the items in your problem set are in `writer.solutions`, the it will return an empty set, which evaluates to False (hence the `not set.difference()`).

Comment: Thanks a ton! This is a good suggestion, but writers.solutions is actually a dictionary. :/

Comment: What is problems?  Can you just compare the dictionary keys?  They are hashable.

Comment: Oh, you're definitely right. I just tried using this method and it worked perfectly! Wow!

Comment: `.difference` is unnecessarily constructing a `set` of the missing items; switch it to `.issubset` (and don't use `not` to negate the result) to avoid the temporary; I believe changing `not problems.difference(writer.solutions)` to `problems.issubset(writer.solutions)` would get the same results with shortcircuiting on first mismatch and no temporaries.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Ah, nice! Haven't used that before.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
[writer for writer in writerList  for problem in [1,2,3] if problem in writer.solutions]
```

Comment: This would create a list with multiple copies of the writer (one for each problem in their solutions list).

Comment: This version helped me when I was searching for partial string matches between two lists, which was surprisingly tricky. `aList = ['apple', 'banana', 'peach']   bList = ['ap', 'pea']   [b for b in bList for a in aList if b in a]`